# Foundation 6 Sticky Menu After jQuery Load()

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, sticky, jquery-load, zurb-foundation-6

I have a HTML file that loads other components (.html files) into it via jQuery load(). In this example i'm loading the menu and footer from an external html file, and Everything is loaded correctly.
My issue is with the menu, i created a sticky menu with Foundation 6 and the "sticky" part isn't working...

If i add my html directly into the page the menu works as expected. But when the same html is loaded into the page from an external file, the menu looses its sticky properties.

_navigation.html:

```
<div class="nav-container" data-sticky-container>
    <div class="" data-sticky data-margin-top='0' data-options="stickTo:top; stickyOn:small;">
        <nav id="myMenu" class="row title-bar">
            <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-10 column">
                <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu">                            
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 column">
                <ul class="menu align-right">
                    <li class="small-12 column"><a class="alert button hollow" href="contacts.html">Get in Touch!</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
$(document).foundation();

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#navigation").load("_navigation.html", function() {
        $(document).foundation('reflow');
    });


    $("footer").load("_footer.html");
});
```

index.html:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>HTML Master Page</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.1/foundation.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="navigation"></div>

        <div id="content" class="row column">
            <h1>Index</h1>
        </div>

        <footer class="expanded"></footer>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.1/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: What happens if you call `$(document).foundation();` after `$("footer").load("_footer.html");`?

Comment: @Yass i had already done that test and nothing changes :(

Comment: What if  you call `foundation()` on the sticky element. There's a line that reads: `<div class="" data-sticky data-margin-top='0' data-options="stickTo:top; stickyOn:small;">`. Add a class to it (e.g. `sticky-footer`) and try calling `$('.sticky-footer').foundation()`.

Comment: My issue isn't with the footer, its with the navigation. Either way, i've tried your suggestion and it doesn't work. The navigation isn't sticking :-/